# Which format of STL file is faster to read: ascii or binary?

Tags: c++, stl

I have to write an STL file with a large no. of triangles (about 2 millions). Currently I am writing and reading it in ascii format which takes too much time. My question is: "whether writing and reading in binary format will save significant amount of time?" Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it? It shouldn't be that hard, or take that long time, to test both variants out.

Comment: Yes, probably, depending on how you implement it.  The ascii version shouldn't be that bad either depending on how you're constructing/writing the data.

Comment: Yes, I am trying it out. Will update. Thanks

Comment: Please show us your I/O serialization code. 2M is not a huge amount of data and ASCII conversion should be an insignificant blip really. I suspect that you're doing something inefficient if you find it "too slow"

Comment: I am sorry guys. My earlier comment seems to be giving a wrong info hence deleting it. Will test and update again.

Comment: I tested after corrections and found out that the binary stl reading is 1.5-2 times faster than ascii stl reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly it will. If you're storing integers in the text file as human-readable numbers then they will all have to be converted to and from their internal 4-byte representation. If you're using binary, you just dump each number as 4 bytes (I assume 4 byte ints, you may use different types)

Without this continual conversion from test strings a binary representation will obviously be faster. The only question is just how fast.

Comment: It came out to be 1.5 - 2 times faster. Thanks

Comment: We once stored serialised object data as XML. Changing it to use a binary representation chopped 20% off the overall time in our program - that was a considerable amount. Write code that works like a computer wants when performance matters, not what's convenient for a human!